# How can I grab specific text from this html file? Using Jsoup functionality in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, jsoup

Code:

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup
fun main(){
    val url = "https://www.google.com/maps/place/?q=place_id:"
    //val placeID:String = "ChIJRVY_etDX3IARGYLVpoq7f68";
    val placeID:String = "ChIJ1zoUGxYE9YgRL399jlxWp6Q";
    val doc = Jsoup.connect(url+placeID).get()
    val text = doc.html()
    //println(text)

    when (text)
    {
        is String -> println("yay");
    }
    //val pID: Collection<String>? = placeID as? String

    //val here: Pair<Int, String>? = text.findLastAnyOf(placeID,0,false);
    var tempLine:String = ""
    tempLine = text.substringAfterLast(placeID)
    val newLength = tempLine.length
    var tempLine2 = tempLine.substringBefore("window.APP_FLAGS")
    println(tempLine2)
}
```

[Output.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q1CEd.jpg)

[The text I want to specifically grab and return](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1OZg.jpg)

I am working on a personal side project and I have hit a wall, where I cannot grab the busy time information from Google's page, this location is Trader Joes.

Comment: Did you try Regex to get the text between `null,[[` and `\n`

Comment: @Jagar I commented out println(tempLine2) and added this code:

`val busyPattern = "..[\\d],[\\d],............[\\d] [A-Z][A-Z]".toRegex()
val matches = busyPattern.findAll(tempLine2)
println(matches)`
Unfortunately my output is now: kotlin.sequences.GeneratorSequence@a38d7a3

Comment: Please find here the first example to how correctly apply regex patterns in Kotlin: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34595791/12053756